# Determine Coordinates of $30^\circ$ Counterclockwise Rotation

Tags: geometry

Determine the coordinates of $A'$, the image of $A$ after a $30^\circ$ counterclockwise rotation about $P\left(3,2\right)$

[image: Graph of Circle of Rotation]

I have figured out that $\overline{PA}=5$ and that a $36.87^\circ$ counterclockwise rotation maps $A'$ onto $(3,7)$, but can't seem to find a way to progress.

Comment: Can you rotate the point (3,4) about the origin by 30 degrees?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\alpha$ is the angle by which you have to rotate $(8,2)$ about $P$ in order to get $A$, then $A=(3+5\cos\alpha,\;2+5\sin\alpha)$ and $\cos\alpha = \frac{3}{5}$ and $\sin\alpha=\frac{4}{5}.$ You get $A'$ by simply rotating $30^{\circ}$ more:
$$
A'=(3+5\cos(\alpha+30^{\circ}),\;2+5\sin(\alpha+30^{\circ})\;)
$$
Now use
$$
\cos(\alpha+\beta) = \cos\alpha\,\cos\beta-\sin\alpha\,\sin\beta \\
\sin(\alpha+\beta) = \sin\alpha\,\cos\beta+\cos\alpha\,\sin\beta
$$
and
$$
\cos 30^{\circ} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
\sin 30^{\circ} = \frac{1}{2}
$$
to get
$$
A'=\left(
3+5\cdot\frac{3}{5}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-5\cdot\frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{2}
\;,\;
2+5\cdot\frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+5\cdot\frac{3}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{2}
\right) \\
= \left(
1+\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}\;,\;
\frac{7}{2}+2\sqrt{3}
\right)
$$